# numpy for python 2.3

Tags: python, numpy, pip, easy-install, python-2.3

I am trying to install numpy for version 2.3 as  I require the oldnumeric package for an old data reduction program.

I tried pip and easy_install, but can't find how to install both for python 2.3 . Any suggestions?

Comment: If the dependencies are not that many/complex I would rather create wrappers or simply look for an alternative and update the script to be up-to-date. Using a separate version of Python just for this is an overkill.

Comment: Maybe [you could simply update your old script code](http://www.numpy.org/old_array_packages.html).

Comment: Problem is that it is not my script code, but an old data reduction pipeline whose dependencies I do not know.

Comment: Well, you could try at least. Perhaps the `numpy.oldnumeric.alter_code1` module mentioned in the link I posted above does fix everything on one go! If it does not then you'll have to manually install an old Python interpreter and the old Numeric package as well.

Comment: ok, I will give it a try and tell you how it went. Thanks!

Comment: OK, tried it, could not get it to run, so ended up installing Anaconda and that solved the problem. Thanks for the help! :)